# number signs in AdoTable.Filter

Tags: database, delphi, ms-access

`AdoTable1.Filter:= 
'Date = #'+FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy', Tomorrow)+ ' #' ;`

Why is Date surrounded with number signs??
Is this Access -specific??

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DrStrangeLove, the `#` sign (hash-marks) is the [delimiter](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6135056.html) for a date field in access, you can check [this](http://www.accessmvp.com/Strive4Peace/Access_Basics_Crystal_080113_Chapter_07.pdf) paper for more info about delimiters in Access.

[Access Basics for Programming: Delimiters](http://www.accessmvp.com/Strive4Peace/Access_Basics_Crystal_080113_Chapter_07.pdf)

Comment: And to answer the other half of the question: Yes, it's Access-specific.

Comment: No, it's NOT Access-specific. It's Jet/ACE-specific. Jet/ACE exists outside of Access, and Access can utilize other datastores and use other date delimiters (depending on context and how you're using your SQL and how you're accessing the data).

Comment: @David-W-Fenton  you are right, but the default database engine for access is Jet/ACE and this engine uses the `#` hash marker as delimiter.